# restricted-use C++ computational types

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion

I would like to have a way of defining computational types (e.g., somethng that acts like a "limited **int**") that do not automatically convert to their base types or to each other--behavior similar to that of typed pointers.

For example, I'd like to be able to define **XCoord** and **YCoord** types to use for X and Y coordinates. I can do that with **typedef,** of course, and it makes my code more explicit, but what I really want is for the compiler to complain when I accidentally pass a Y coordinate as a function call argument when I should have used an X coordinate. Another use case is associating dimensional units with numbers, to get a complaint if one accidentally adds a height-in-meters number to a weight-in-grams.

Yes, I know, this example is simplistic and glosses over many problems. I'd want to specify numeric values. I'd want to loop through ranges of values. I'd want to subtract two **XCoord** values (and get an **int**?). I'd want to use them as array subscripts. I'm sure there's a whole host of usages I haven't thought about in detail--and while it would be nice to have them all work transparently, I'm not averse to a little syntactic inconvenience (like a member function invocation) in some usages.

I can mostly see how to hack together a solution with templates and operator overloading, and probably get much of what I want. I'm hoping, however, that there is a solution out there whose creators have already done the hard work and explored the corner cases and made the appropriate compromises between convenience and function.

And, of course, they're just basic types with added compile-time checking--so the solution should have zero run-time performance penalties relative to the basic types, just like **typedef**

Does such a thing exist? Is a solution using language contructs so mind-numbingly complex and full of surprises that I would be better off using plain old **typedefs** and a **lint**-like tool instead? And if so, is there such a tool?

Answer (score 1):

I believe [boost](http://www.boost.org/).[serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)'s [BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html) should fit your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [boost::units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_units.html)?

Answer (score 1):

> I can mostly see how to hack together a solution with templates and operator overloading, and probably get much of what I want. I'm hoping, however, that there is a solution out there whose creators have already done the hard work and explored the corner cases and made the appropriate compromises between convenience and function.

In my experience those compromises vary depending on the type and application.  For example, whether construction from and/or conversion to base type are implicit, whether it's meaningful to use bitwise operators on two values of the type, or logical operators, pre/post incrementing/decrement, `+=` `*=` etc..  Some of these things may be able to be optionally and concisely specified using CRTP, or a type-creation preprocessor macro that accepts optional arguments with other macros representing groups of such functions.  I have done this kind of thing before in a couple different contexts, but am not aware of any freely available and similarly flexible reusable library.  If you are implementing this using macros, it's nice that you can thereby specify the class name to create a unique type.  (For an example, see the BENUM library in the boost vault - http://www.boostpro.com/vault).  Boost's BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF has this benefit but lacks flexibility.

If you use templates directly, as in `template <typename T> class Unique { ... };`, then you'll find you can't create two distinct types with the same underlying (template parameter) type.  You can resolve this by passing some unique number to the template, as in `template <typename T, int Id>`.  This requires manually providing unique ints each time you instantiate the template - a maintenance pain.  If you must automate this allocation and all usage is within one file, you can supply `__LINE__` (or have a macro do it), otherwise perhaps template on const char* as well and give it `__FILE__` or look for a compiler-specific preprocessor extension to generate suitably unique numbers/ids.